# Псевдослучайное число из промежутка [-n;n)

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! У меня вот такой вопрос по коду, подскажите по заданию, я правильно написал код или что не правильно? Вот задание:

> Создайте программу, которая будет генерировать и выводить на экран
> вещественное псевдослучайное число из промежутка [-3;3).

```
public class MathRandom {
    public static void main(String args[]){
      final int min = -3;
      final int max = 3;
        double  ran = Math.random()* min * max;
        System.out.println("Число из промежутка -> [-3;3) = " + ran);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет.

ran = Math.random() будет в интервале [0:1]. Его надо растянуть на интервал от min до max, а затем "сцентрировать", прибавив min.

```
Random rd = new Random();
......
ran = rd.nextDouble();
ran = (ran*(imax-imin)+imin);
```

Это, если нужны разные псевдослучайные числа в цикле, а Math.random() будет возвращать одно и то же.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как правильно вычисляется промежуток или по какой формуле
если например вот такой диапазон чисел-3;3),(-3;3],[-3;3] и [-3;3) или такой (-3;-3),(-3;-3],[-3;-3] и [-3;-3)

Comment: В любом случае для min < max надо max - min. Другими словами, вычисляете gap = max-min; if (gap < 0) gap = -gap; if (gap == 0) Error();

Comment: С включением/исключением границ в интервале все не так просто. <a href="http://www.techtalkz.com/java/155349-random-real-number-between-0-inclusive-1-inclusive-7.html">Вот обсуждение</a> возможных реализаций генерации вещственного числа в интервале [0,1] на основе Math.random() или его исходного кода (у большинства из них есть недочеты в распределении вероятностей, которыми вы можете пренебречь в зависимости от требуемой точности). Из простейших реализаций вот, например: `while ((R = Math.random()*2) > 1.0) {}`

Answer (score 2):

Вот даст вам `Math.random()` 0,5 - и результат будет -4,5 - конечно, неправильно.

```
double ran = Math.random() * (max - min) - (max - min) / 2;
// или, после упрощения
double ran =  (max - min) * (Math.random() - 0.5);
```

Comment: да можно бы было просто 6 поставить вместо (max-min), т.к. если эти числа не симметричны относительно 0, то выражение не имеет смысла(к примеру max = 4, min =-2).

Comment: Почему ? Чем плох интервал [-2:4] ? 

Просто напишите общую формулу.